# ES6 Static Properties Subtle (Mis)Behavior in Inheritance

Tags: javascript

When one defines a static property on an ES6 class, and you have other classes that extend that class, any change to the property on the parent class will seem to change the value on all subclasses. This seems to be a subtle prototype chain issue. If you first set the property value on the subclass then it seems to "own" it--i.e. it won't reflect changes to the super class. My issue is that I want a class property that flags a guaranteed one-time-only initialization the first time a class is used, and because this is a library/framework I don't want to have to force users to explicitly set the static value in their own subclass definitions. Other than having a global that tracks it instead, is there any other way to keep static properties separate across subclasses?

Code that demonstrates problem:

```
class Class1 {
    static get initialized() { return this.$initialized }
    static set initialized(flag) { this.$initialized = flag}
}
class Class2 extends Class1 {}
```

`Class1.initialized` -> undefined

`Class1.initialized = false;`

`Class2.initialized` -> false

`Class1.initialized = true;`

`Class2.initialized` -> true

Comment: There is no such thing as _static properties_ in ES6. There are only static methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `$initialized` property is inherited as well, so once the superclass is initialised then this will be reflected in all subclasses. You can write your getter so that it ignores inherited properties though:

```
class Class1 {
    static get initialized() {
      return this.hasOwnProperty("$initialized")
        ? this.$initialized
        : undefined; // or whatever default value you want
    }
    static set initialized(flag) {
      this.$initialized = flag
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bergi - please reiterate to our unsuspecting friend that `$initialized` is not static as the question terminology suggests. The use of `this` in your answer, and the OP question is the clue to that fact. It is possible the OP mistakenly (still) believes static properties exist in JS.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Of course it is, it's a property of the class object? That's what I would call "static".

Comment: Nope - it exists in the prototype inheritance chain as a property of the created Object. There is no way to create a property on an Class that can be called statically.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What do you mean by "created object"? In `Class1.initialized` or `Class1.$initialized`, there is no instance of the class anywhere. Of course classes (i.e. constructor functions) are just objects that can have properties like everything else in JS.

Comment: _Of course classes (i.e. constructor functions) are just objects that can have properties like everything else in JS._ Exactly, the function object has the property available on the prototype chain. Given the OPs question and your answer, `Class2.$initialized` Will return the value stored in `Class1.$initialized` property.

Comment: @RandyCasburn In any case, the property is available on `Class1` (or things inheriting from it), not on `Class1.prototype` (or things inheriting from it), so I would call that a *static* property (regardless whether own or inherited). Is there anything wrong with my terminology?

Comment: @RandyCasburn And yes, that `Class2.$initialized` will return the inherited value is just what I'm saying in my answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I meant "static" in the JS sense, and not in a C sense